# Window Placement on Unity doesn't open programs on workspaces 3 and 4, how can I fix it?

Tags: unity, compiz

I'm working on an article for my site about using window placement rules. On Ubuntu Classic I can create all the rules I want (open evolution on workspace 2, liferea on workspace 3, gwibber on workspace 4 and so on) but on Unity if I assign a program to workspace 3 or 4 it will be opened on workspace 2.

I disabled the Unity plugin but that leaves me with no panels and just a wallpaper. Can someone help me out with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i fixed the problem... To place/open programs on workspace 3 and 4 you also need to change the Y Viewport Positions. For opening programs on workspace 1 and 2 you only need to set the X Viewport position and leave Y viewport on 1. To open programs on workspace 3 change X Viewport Position to 1 and Y Viewport Position to 2. To open a program on workspace 4 change X Viewport Position to 2 and change Y Viewport Position to 2.

Workspace 1: X Viewport Position 1 - Y Viewport Position 1

Workspace 2: X Viewport Position 2 - Y Viewport Position 1

Workspace 3: X Viewport Position 1 - Y Viewport Position 2

Workspace 4: X Viewport Position 2 - Y Viewport Position 2